# Shiny as Stand-Alone Program

Tags: r, macos, shiny

I wrote a Shiny app, and now I need to turn it into a Stand-Alone Program. The reasoning behind this is that I need to share the app but can't do this with shinyapps.io or a server as I need the app to be able to access user's folders. 
So far, I found these 2 tutorials: [deploying-desktop-apps](https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/) and [packaging-your-shiny-app](http://blog.analytixware.com/2014/03/packaging-your-shiny-app-as-windows.html). Both of them (supposedly) work on Windows, but I have a Mac, and I want to app to be available for users of all systems, or at least Mac and Linux. Any thoughts and suggestions would be appreciated!

I actually tried to follow the tutorial mentioned above, and can't even install R-portable for my Mac. So I'm looking for something different.

Running a Virtual Machine to follow Windows tutorial is an option, but in this case, the app will be Windows-specific, and I don't want this.

Comment: this may help get you a standalone R build for macOS https://superuser.com/questions/939070/a-self-contained-r-in-os-x but (for FYI) R usage tends to track with browser usage and that's near 90% Windows, so you're solving for very niche cases unless your userbase is on linux/macOS (I'm not a Windows user and really don't like having to accommodate that terrible computing platform, but it is what it is). That same build technique shld work for linux-ish systems as well.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thank you for the link! I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by "R usage tends to track with browser usage and that's near 90% Windows, so you're solving for very niche cases unless your userbase is on linux/macOS". Could you elaborate? I'm not a Windows user as well, I wrote about Windows only because the tutorials are Windows-based...

Comment: Ah! I was merely pointing out that the vast, vast, vast, vast majority of R folk are Windows users so your App needs to work there first and foremost if it's for general release. If it's targeting known non-Windows folks (yay!) then that link (modified slighlty for linux since it has no "aqua" shld work).

Answer (score 1):

This thread is really old I know, but I'm also trying to find answers on creating a standalone version of R for Mac.

This would support for
https://github.com/chasemc/electricShine
which supports Windows